# ng-click toggle variable and update entire page

Tags: angularjs

I have a global variable called `RecruiterDashboard.IsColdList`. It is a boolean that decides rather to run one directive or another. When the page is loaded the variable is made either true or false through normal scripting.

What I want to do is allow the user to toggle through an ng-click rather to show this other directive or not, so I made an ng-click and set `RecruiterDashboard.IsColdList` from 'false' to 'true'. Problem is this doesn't reload the angular page and fire the controllers off. How do make the page run through the controllers again?

This is what I have so far:

```
$scope.showColdList = function (projId) {
        RecruiterDashboard.isColdList = true;
    };
```

I want to point out that I am not using angular routing. I am using C# MVC.

My logic looks like so:

```
callPanelControllers.controller('callPanelController', function($scope) {
    $scope.isColdList = RecruiterDashboard.isColdList;
});

callPanelControllers.controller('incomingCall', function ($scope) {
     $scope.showColdList = function () {
        RecruiterDashboard.isColdList = true;
    };
});

<div ng-click="showColdList()" ng-controller="incomingCall"></div>
<div ng-controller="callPanelController">
    <cold-list ng-show="isColdList"></cold-list>
</div>
```

Comment: angular should "reload". Can you add the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: well it fires the stuff in that single controller but not the other controllers

Comment: How are you controlling which directive is shown? Can you paste more of the code, as Acsisr suggested?

Comment: I added some more detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had developed sort of a hack, so that the entire content inside of a given element is reloaded on change of a certain variable.

```
csapp.directive("csReloadOn", ["$timeout", function ($timeout) {

    var getTemplate = function () {
        return '<div ng-if="doRefreshPageOnModeChange"><div ng-transclude=""></div></div>';
    };

    var linkFunction = function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.doRefreshPageOnModeChange = true;

        scope.$watch(attrs.csReloadOn, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal === oldVal) return;

            scope.doRefreshPageOnModeChange = false;
            $timeout(function () { scope.doRefreshPageOnModeChange = true; }, 100);
        });
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        transclude: true,
        template: getTemplate,
        link: linkFunction
    };
}]);
```

you can use it like

```
     <div cs-reload-on="{{pagemode}}"> 
           <!-- your html here-->     
      </div>
```

so it just removes and re-renders the complete content inside of the div, so everything is reinitialized etc etc.